# Working with python scikit-learn ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.mixture.gmm' how i solve this without downgrading scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.mixture.gmm'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TUIv.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the following import statement instead:

```py
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture as gmm
```

This one should work with newer version of scikit-learn.